# How to solve Apostrophe matter in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I don't fix the matter of Apostrophe in PHP, when I input Apostrophe(') into my text field every time I sow (syntax error, unexpected T_STRING)
Thous are my codes: Please Some one help me in easy way, Thank you.

register.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<div id="reg">
<?php
if( isset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && is_array($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && count($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) >0 ) {
    echo '<ul class="err">';
    foreach($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] as $msg) {
        echo '<li>',$msg,'</li>'; 
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    unset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']);
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action='register-exec.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' name='loginForm' id='loginForm'>
<table width='629' height='211' border='0' align='center' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='0'>
<tr>
<th align='left'>First Name :</th>
<td><input name='fname' type='text' class='textfield' id='fname' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th align='left'>Last Name :</th>
<td><input name='lname' type='text' class='textfield' id='lname' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th align='left'>Email :</th>
<td><input name='email' type='text' class='textfield' id='email'  /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th width='166' align='left'>UserName :</th>
<td width='459'><input name='login' type='text' class='textfield' id='login'  /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th align='left'>Password :</th>
<td><input name='password' type='password' class='textfield' id='password'  /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th align='left'>Confirm Password :</th>
<td><input name='cpassword' type='password' class='textfield' id='cpassword'  /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Country :</td>
<td><select name='country' id='country'>
  <option value='' selected></option>
        <option value='San Marino'>San Marino</option>
        <option value='Saudi Arabia'>Saudi Arabia</option>
         <option value='Seychelles'>Seychelles</option>
         <option value='Singapore'>Singapore</option>
         <option value='Slovakia'>Slovakia</option>
        <option value='Slovenia'>Slovenia</option>
       <option value='Solomon Islands'>Solomon Islands</option>
      <option value='South Africa'>South Africa</option>
      <option value='Spain'>Spain</option>
      <option value='Sri Lanka'>Sri Lanka</option>
     <option value='St.Pierre and Miquelon'>St.Pierre and Miquelon</option>
       <option value='St.Vincent and the Grenadines'>St.Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
          <option value='Sweden'>Sweden</option>
         <option value='Switzerland'>Switzerland</option>
        <option value='Syria'>Syria</option>
         <option value='Taiwan '>Taiwan </option>
         <option value='Tajikistan'>Tajikistan</option>
         <option value='Thailand'>Thailand</option>
         <option value='Trinidad and Tobago'>Trinidad and Tobago</option>
         <option value='Turkey'>Turkey</option>
         <option value='Turkmenistan'>Turkmenistan</option>
         <option value='Turks and Caicos Islands'>Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
         <option value='Ukraine'>Ukraine</option>
         <option value='UAE'>UAE</option>
         <option value='UK'>UK</option>
        <option value='USA'>USA</option>
       <option value='Uruguay'>Uruguay</option>
      <option value='Uzbekistan'>Uzbekistan</option>
     <option value='Vanuatu'>Vanuatu</option>
    <option value='Vatican City'>Vatican City</option>
   <option value='Vietnam'>Vietnam</option>
   <option value='Virgin Islands (GB)'>Virgin Islands (GB)</option>
  <option value='Virgin Islands (U.S.) '>Virgin Islands (U.S.) </option>
  <option value='Wallis and Futuna Islands'>Wallis and Futuna Islands</option>
  <option value='Yemen'>Yemen</option>
 <option value='Yugoslavia'>Yugoslavia</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>City :</td>
<td><input name='city' type='text' class='textfield' id='city'  /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Upload Image :</td>
<td>        <input type='file' name='image' id='image' />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Register' /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

register-exec.php

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();

//Include database connection details
require_once('config2.php');

//Array to store validation errors
$errmsg_arr = array();

//Validation error flag
$errflag = false;

//Connect to mysql server
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if(!$link) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select database
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
if(!$db) {
    die("Unable to select database");
}

//Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

//Sanitize the POST values
$fname = clean($_POST['fname']);
$lname = clean($_POST['lname']);
$email = clean($_POST['email']);
$login = clean($_POST['login']);
$password = clean($_POST['password']);
$cpassword = clean($_POST['cpassword']);
$country = clean($_POST['country']);
$city = clean($_POST['city']);

//Input Validations
if($fname == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'First name missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($lname == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Last name missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($email == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Email missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($login == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Login ID missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($password == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($cpassword == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Confirm password missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($country == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Country is missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($city == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'City is mising';
    $errflag = true;
}
if( strcmp($password, $cpassword) != 0 ) {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Passwords do not match';
    $errflag = true;
}

//Check for duplicate email
if($email != '') {
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='$email'";
    $result = mysql_query($qry);
    if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            $errmsg_arr[] = 'Email ID already in use';
            $errflag = true;
        }
        @mysql_free_result($result);
    }
    else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
}

//Check for duplicate login ID
if($login != '') {
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE login='$login'";
    $result = mysql_query($qry);
    if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            $errmsg_arr[] = 'Login ID already in use';
            $errflag = true;
        }
        @mysql_free_result($result);
    }
    else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
}

//If there are input validations, redirect back to the registration form
if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: index.php?page=register");
    exit();
}

// Variable for hours
$hourdiff = "5"; // hours difference between server time and local time

// Nothing needs to be changed below here unless you want to change
// the format of the date (see above for URL of options) or your local
// time is behind the server time
$timeadjust = ($hourdiff * 3600);
$melbdate = date("l, d M Y h:i:s a",time() + $timeadjust);
echo $melbdate;

// Generates activation code simple 4 digit number
$activ_code = rand(1000,9999);

$email = $_POST['email'];
$login = $_POST['login'];

//Ip Address Varified
$http_client_ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
$http_x_forwarded_for = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
$remote_addr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if (!empty($http_client_ip)) {
$ip_address = $http_client_ip;
}elseif (!empty($http_x_forwarded_for)) {
$ip_address = $http_x_forwarded_for;
}else {
$ip_address = $remote_addr;
}

$ip_address = $ip_address;


//Image upload

$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
$image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);


//Create INSERT query
$qry = "INSERT INTO members(firstname, lastname, email, login, passwd,country,city,time,ip,name,image,activation_code) VALUES('$fname','$lname','$email','$login','".($_POST['password'])."','$country','$city','$melbdate','$ip_address','$image_name','$image','$activ_code')";
$result = @mysql_query($qry);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    header("location: register-success.php");
    exit();
}else {
    die("Query failed");
}
?>
```

Comment: Which line do you get that message in?

Comment: Where does your error occur? That's a lot of code you posted in there. What's the full error message?

Comment: If you have to dump all of your code here you didn't do enough debugging on your own.

Comment: Where are you trying to use it? Most probs you are using it in echo's that you use ' to encase. Could use " instead and put ' inside of them.

Comment: Your code has SQL injections and isn't secure.

Comment: you use mysql when you should be using mysqli, and you are using plain queries, when you should prepare them and let the db driver make the escaping and cleaning for you. You are self-sql injecting

Comment: scape that `'` character

Comment: Every thing work good but when I use apostrophe (') on my text field then it will show me Query failed.

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `function clean($str)` problem is there, you can remove this function and add `mysql_real_escape_string()` into every `$_POST[]` like this:

```
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
$lname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$login = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$cpassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cpassword']);
$country = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country']);
$city = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city']);
```

I think this will work.